# Confusion in the algorithms's output

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I was solving various algorithm questions on time and space complexity- recursive calls to be more specific. I have below simple pseudo code which I came across :

```
    doSomething(m)
    if m == 1 then
     return 1
    else
     return doSomething(random(1, m));
```

So my question does this code return 1 every time? (I know in the worst case it can select the same random number every time and go into infinite loop). But speaking from actual code point of view- does this return 1 every time (in java or any programming language)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice? Besides the near-impossible infinite loop case, it's also possible that this will hit a max recursion depth or have a stack overflow error. But this is very unlikely; assuming a well-distributed random number generator, `m` will be halved on average each function execution. So the function will recurse roughly `log2(m)` times on average, and will always return `1` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought as well. But theoretically speaking, can't the random number generator always generate the same number ?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. It can absolutely generate the same number every time. That's where the infinite case comes into play. In practice, with a good RNG, it will eventually generate different numbers.

Comment: whats your take on worst case and average case number of calls to last line ?

Answer (score 0):

The statement `if m == 1 then return 1` represents the only base case in the algorithm. Based upon this we can be sure that the outcome of the algorithm, barring any unlikely infinite execution, will be 1.

Comment: whats your take on worst case and average case number of calls to last line ? @ajxs

Answer (score 0):

The only logical output is:

```
if m == 1 then
     return 1

1 as the answer.
```

Unless random(1, m) includes any number between 1 and m not including 1 and m like **1 < n < m**, in that case its an infinite loop.

This code reminds me of below factorial typo:

```
if (number == 0)
     return 0;
```

should be:

```
if (number == 1)
    return 1;
```

where the answer is always 0.

```
public static double factorial_Recursion(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return number*factorial_Recursion(number - 1);
}
```

Comment: whats your take on worst case and average case number of calls to last line ?